# Json DeserializeObject into class with dynamic property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to convert a string of JSON data into a C# class object. However I'm having an issue with a small part of the JSON which is dynamic in nature.

The part of the JSON is below:

```
"contact": [{
    "comment": null,
    "type": {
        "id": "cell",
        "name": "Example name"
    },
    "preferred": true,
    "value": {
        "country": "7",
        "formatted": "+7 (702) 344-3423-3",
        "number": "3498908",
        "city": "702"
    }
},
{
    "type": {
        "id": "email",
        "name": "Email example"
    },
    "preferred": false,
    "value": "name@mail.com"
}]
```

C# classes

```
public class Value
{
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string formatted { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public bool preferred { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

C# Code

```
 Contact contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(result);
```

The format of "value" changes depending on the contact information. Is it possible to map value both as a string and also class Value.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: to me it look like you got the class structure wrong. looks like there is a base class Value and two other classes AddressValue and EmailValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can literally just use `dynamic`, i.e.

```
public dynamic value { get; set; }
```

If it looks like an object, it will be materialized as a `JObject`, which can be used via the `dynamic` API, so `.value.country` will work, etc. If it looks like an integer, bool or string: it will be materialized as such. Arrays will also be handled suitably. So: you can check whether `.value is string`, etc. Note that this won't use your `Value` type, and doing so is more complex, but: meh; you get the data. You can always switch that out manually.

It will also behave like this if you use `object` instead of `dynamic`, but then it is harder to access the inner properties.

Comment: Thanks Marc, this worked for me. 

I changed the property to 

`public dynamic value { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Contact contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(result[0]);
```

As you can see in the JSON, it's

```
"contact": [
```

Indicating an array, currently you're just passing the entire array

Comment: I don't think that's the point of the question; I think OP is saying "here's a fragment of a larger object", in which there is a `Contact[]` or `List<Contact>` named `contact`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're sure that the JSON comes always with the same structure, the best is to use a `dynamic` variable instead of `deserialize` it into a class.

If you like to work with classes you can always build your own on `runtime` using `reflection`. But that's like *killing a fly with a cannon* and you're probably won't need it, so just use a `dynamic` variable instead, it's the best to work with JSON strings.